# Open id for my html website

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, web-applications, openid

First up all I am a web developer (very weak in Application side).

My website is in `.html` ,my question is ,is it possible to use `open id` concept in my html page ,or i want to change it into php or some other.

After login using open id one discussion form also in my page.

Is it all possible in .html ? Is it discussion form also possible to do using  open id concept.
any demo or link will be very help full for me.

Comment: If you want to use OpenID, you obviously want to enable user login, for which you'll need a server-side language instead of plain HTML pages.

Comment: my webpage is like a blog,user can watch the video ,and they can post comments after login, so  So i should change

Comment: Is it a PHP blog? Something like Wordpress, or have you made it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

For any type of login or comments you will need to use php with a database. You might be able to pull it off with jQuery.

http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html - Login Tutorial
http://www.allsyntax.com/tutorials/PHP/24/Building-a-Comments-Script/1.php - Comments Tutorial

Is this what you were looking for or something else?

Comment: yea u r right,but in my site i have facebook like button and a twitter tweet button,clicking on like button it will show facebook login page and after login it will come to my site,and it will show the like count also.For that i am using a script that was provided by fb itself,I am searching something like that for open id also,i am not sure whether it possible.